# Javascript for of loop mistakes

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
function nameGenerator(){
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mon__sect-row-inner');

for (const element of elements) {
    const currentText = element.querySelector('.entry-title-inner').innerText;
    for (setText of currentText)
        setText = element.querySelector('.render-roller');
        console.log(currentText);
        setText.setAttribute("data-roll-name",currentText)
}
```

I would like this to loop through the first item in Selector 1 and then all the sub arrays under Selector 1 but in Selector 2. Then back to Selector 1 item 2 and then all items for the sub array there. Any ideas why its not doing that? Its going array 1 item 1 then Array 2 item 1 then Array 1 item 2 etc.

```
<table id="pagecontent" class="w-100 stats monster" data-proficiency-dice-mode="bonus"><tr><th class="border" colspan="6"></th></tr><tr>
            <th class="rnd-name mon__name--token" colspan="6" data-page="bestiary.html" data-source="TCE" data-hash="adult%20red%20dracolich_tce" data-extension="{}">
                <div class="name-inner">
                    <div class="ve-flex-v-center">
                        <h1 class="stats-name copyable m-0" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" onclick="Renderer.utils._pHandleNameClick(this)">Adult Red Dracolich</h1>
                        
                        
            </div>
            <div class="stats-source ve-flex-v-baseline">
                <a href="book.html#tce,page:137" class="help-subtle stats-source-abbreviation sourceTCE" title="Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything">TCE</a>

                 <a href="book.html#tce,page:137" class="rd__stats-name-page ml-1" title="Page 137">p137</a>

                
            </div>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr><tr><td colspan="6">
    <div class="mon__wrp-size-type-align--token"><i>Huge Undead, Chaotic Evil</i></div>
</td></tr><tr><td class="divider" colspan="6"><div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><div class="mon__wrp-avoid-token"><strong>Armor Class</strong> 19 (natural armor)</div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><div class="mon__wrp-avoid-token"><strong>Hit Points</strong> 256 (<span class="roller render-roller" title="Hit Points. Click to roll. SHIFT/CTRL to roll twice." data-roll-name="Hit Points" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;19d12 + 133&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Hit Points&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;19d12 + 133&quot;}">19d12 + 133</span>)</div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Speed</strong> 40 ft., climb 40 ft., fly 80 ft.</td></tr><tr><td class="divider" colspan="6"><div></div></td></tr><tr class="mon__ability-names">
    <th>STR</th><th>DEX</th><th>CON</th><th>INT</th><th>WIS</th><th>CHA</th>
</tr><tr class="mon__ability-scores">
    <td><span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionModsModified" title="Strength. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Strength" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;abilityCheck&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;str&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Strength&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;27 (+8)&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+8&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+8&quot;}">27 (<a href="talespire://dice/Strength:1D20+8" class="talespireLink">+8</a>)</span></td><td><span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionModsModified" title="Dexterity. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Dexterity" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;abilityCheck&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;dex&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Dexterity&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;10 (+0)&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+0&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+0&quot;}">10 (<a href="talespire://dice/Dexterity:1D20+0" class="talespireLink">+0</a>)</span></td><td><span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionModsModified" title="Constitution. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Constitution" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;abilityCheck&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;con&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Constitution&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;25 (+7)&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+7&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+7&quot;}">25 (<a href="talespire://dice/Constitution:1D20+7" class="talespireLink">+7</a>)</span></td><td><span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionModsModified" title="Intelligence. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Intelligence" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;abilityCheck&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;int&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Intelligence&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;16 (+3)&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+3&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+3&quot;}">16 (<a href="talespire://dice/Intelligence:1D20+3" class="talespireLink">+3</a>)</span></td><td><span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionModsModified" title="Wisdom. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Wisdom" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;abilityCheck&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;wis&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Wisdom&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;13 (+1)&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+1&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+1&quot;}">13 (<a href="talespire://dice/Wisdom:1D20+1" class="talespireLink">+1</a>)</span></td><td><span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionModsModified" title="Charisma. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Charisma" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;abilityCheck&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;cha&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Charisma&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;21 (+5)&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+5&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+5&quot;}">21 (<a href="talespire://dice/Charisma:1D20+5" class="talespireLink">+5</a>)</span></td>
</tr><tr><td class="divider" colspan="6"><div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Saving Throws</strong> <span>Dex <span class="roller render-roller" title="Dexterity save. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Dexterity save" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;savingThrow&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;dex&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Dexterity save&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+6&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+6&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+6&quot;}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 0"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+6</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+1d12 + 0</span></span></span>, <span>Con <span class="roller render-roller" title="Constitution save. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Constitution save" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;savingThrow&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;con&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Constitution save&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+13&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+13&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+13&quot;}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 7"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+13</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+1d12 + 7</span></span></span>, <span>Wis <span class="roller render-roller" title="Wisdom save. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Wisdom save" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;savingThrow&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;wis&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Wisdom save&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+7&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+7&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+7&quot;}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 1"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+7</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+1d12 + 1</span></span></span>, <span>Cha <span class="roller render-roller" title="Charisma save. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Charisma save" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;savingThrow&quot;,&quot;ability&quot;:&quot;cha&quot;},&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Charisma save&quot;,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+11&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+11&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+11&quot;}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 5"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+11</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+1d12 + 5</span></span></span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Skills</strong> <span data-mon-skill="Perception|+13"><span class="help help--hover" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="skill" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="perception_phb" data-vet-is-faux-page="true" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">Perception</span> <span class="roller render-roller" title="Perception. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Perception" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;skillCheck&quot;,&quot;skill&quot;:&quot;perception&quot;},&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+13&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Perception&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+13&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+13&quot;}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+2d12 + 1"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+13</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+2d12 + 1</span></span></span>, <span data-mon-skill="Stealth|+6"><span class="help help--hover" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="skill" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="stealth_phb" data-vet-is-faux-page="true" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">Stealth</span> <span class="roller render-roller" title="Stealth. Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." data-roll-name="Stealth" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;skillCheck&quot;,&quot;skill&quot;:&quot;stealth&quot;},&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+6&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Stealth&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+6&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+6&quot;}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 0"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+6</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+1d12 + 0</span></span></span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Damage Resistances</strong> necrotic</td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Damage Immunities</strong> fire, poison</td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Condition Immunities</strong> <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#charmed_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="charmed_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">charmed</a>, <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#exhaustion_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="exhaustion_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">exhaustion</a>, <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#frightened_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="frightened_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">frightened</a>, <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#paralyzed_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="paralyzed_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">paralyzed</a>, <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#poisoned_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="poisoned_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">poisoned</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Senses</strong> <span class="help help--hover" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="sense" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="blindsight_phb" data-vet-is-faux-page="true" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">blindsight</span> 60 ft., <span class="help help--hover" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="sense" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="darkvision_phb" data-vet-is-faux-page="true" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">darkvision</span> 120 ft., passive Perception 23</td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Languages</strong> Common, Draconic</td></tr><tr class="relative"><td colspan="3"><strong>Challenge</strong>
    <span>17 (18,000 XP)</span>
    <button id="btn-scale-cr" title="Scale Creature By CR (Highly Experimental)" class="mon__btn-scale-cr btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span></button>
    <button id="btn-reset-cr" title="Reset CR Scaling" class="mon__btn-reset-cr btn btn-xs btn-default" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
</td><td colspan="3" class="text-right"><strong>Proficiency Bonus</strong> +6</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td class="divider" colspan="6"><div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="mon__sect-row-inner"><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="1"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Legendary Resistance (3/Day).</span></span> <p>If the dracolich fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="2"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Magic Resistance.</span></span> <p>The dracolich has advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="mon__stat-header-underline"><h3 class="mon__sect-header-inner">Actions</h3></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="mon__sect-row-inner"><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="3"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Multiattack.</span></span> <p>The dracolich can use its Frightful Presence. It then makes three attacks: one with its bite and two with its claws.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="4"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Bite.</span></span> <p><i>Melee Weapon Attack:</i> <span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+14&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+14&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+14&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;hit&quot;}}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 8"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+14</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+<a href="talespire://dice/null:1d12+8" class="talespireLink">(1d12+8)</a></span></span> to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. <i>Hit:</i> 19 (<span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll a critical hit, CTRL to half damage (rounding down)." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;2d10 + 8&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;damage&quot;}"><a href="talespire://dice/null:2d10+8" class="talespireLink">(2d10+8)</a></span>) piercing damage plus 7 (<span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll a critical hit, CTRL to half damage (rounding down)." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;2d6&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;damage&quot;}"><a href="talespire://dice/null:2d6" class="talespireLink">(2d6)</a></span>) fire damage.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="5"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Claw.</span></span> <p><i>Melee Weapon Attack:</i> <span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+14&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+14&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+14&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;hit&quot;}}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 8"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+14</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+<a href="talespire://dice/null:1d12+8" class="talespireLink">(1d12+8)</a></span></span> to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. <i>Hit:</i> 15 (<span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll a critical hit, CTRL to half damage (rounding down)." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;2d6 + 8&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;damage&quot;}"><a href="talespire://dice/null:2d6+8" class="talespireLink">(2d6+8)</a></span>) slashing damage.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="6"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Tail.</span></span> <p><i>Melee Weapon Attack:</i> <span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll with advantage, CTRL to roll with disadvantage." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;+14&quot;,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d20+14&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;d20&quot;,&quot;d20mod&quot;:&quot;+14&quot;,&quot;context&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;hit&quot;}}" data-roll-prof-type="d20" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 8"><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-bonus">+14</span><span class="rd__roller--roll-prof-dice">+<a href="talespire://dice/null:1d12+8" class="talespireLink">(1d12+8)</a></span></span> to hit, reach 15 ft., one target. <i>Hit:</i> 17 (<span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll a critical hit, CTRL to half damage (rounding down)." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;2d8 + 8&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;damage&quot;}"><a href="talespire://dice/null:2d8+8" class="talespireLink">(2d8+8)</a></span>) bludgeoning damage.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="7"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Frightful Presence.</span></span> <p>Each creature of the dracolich's choice that is within 120 feet of the dracolich and aware of it must succeed on a DC <span class="rd__dc rd__dc--rollable" data-roll-prof-type="dc" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 13"><span class="rd__dc--rollable-text">19</span><span class="rd__dc--rollable-dice">+1d12 + 13</span></span> Wisdom saving throw or become <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#frightened_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="frightened_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">frightened</a> for 1 minute. A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success. If a creature's saving throw is successful or the effect ends for it, the creature is immune to the dracolich's Frightful Presence for the next 24 hours.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div><div class="rd__b  rd__b--3"><span class="rd__h rd__h--3" data-title-index="8"> <span class="entry-title-inner">Fire Breath (Recharge <span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT/CTRL to roll twice." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;1d6&quot;,&quot;successThresh&quot;:2,&quot;successMax&quot;:6,&quot;displayText&quot;:&quot;5–6&quot;,&quot;chanceSuccessText&quot;:&quot;Recharged!&quot;,&quot;chanceFailureText&quot;:&quot;Did not recharge&quot;}">5–6</span>).</span></span> <p>The dracolich exhales fire in a 60-foot cone. Each creature in that area must make a DC <span class="rd__dc rd__dc--rollable" data-roll-prof-type="dc" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 15"><span class="rd__dc--rollable-text">21</span><span class="rd__dc--rollable-dice">+1d12 + 15</span></span> Dexterity saving throw, taking 63 (<span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll a critical hit, CTRL to half damage (rounding down)." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;18d6&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;damage&quot;}"><a href="talespire://dice/null:18d6" class="talespireLink">(18d6)</a></span>) fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.</p><div class="rd__spc-inline-post"></div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="mon__stat-header-underline"><h3 class="mon__sect-header-inner">Legendary Actions</h3></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6">The dracolich can take 3 legendary actions, choosing from the options below. Only one legendary action can be used at a time and only at the end of another creature's turn. The dracolich regains spent legendary actions at the start of its turn.</td></tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="mon__sect-row-inner"><ul class="rd__list rd__list-hang-notitle"><li class="rd__li "><p class="rd__p-list-item"><span class="bold rd__list-item-name">Detect.</span> The dracolich makes a Wisdom (<span class="help help--hover" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="skill" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="perception_phb" data-vet-is-faux-page="true" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">Perception</span>) check.</p></li><li class="rd__li "><p class="rd__p-list-item"><span class="bold rd__list-item-name">Tail Attack.</span> The dracolich makes a tail attack.</p></li><li class="rd__li "><p class="rd__p-list-item"><span class="bold rd__list-item-name">Wing Attack (Costs 2 Actions).</span> The dracolich beats its wings. Each creature within 10 feet of the dracolich must succeed on a DC <span class="rd__dc rd__dc--rollable" data-roll-prof-type="dc" data-roll-prof-dice="+1d12 + 16"><span class="rd__dc--rollable-text">22</span><span class="rd__dc--rollable-dice">+1d12 + 16</span></span> Dexterity saving throw or take 15 (<span class="roller render-roller TSExtensionAttacksModified" title="Click to roll. SHIFT to roll a critical hit, CTRL to half damage (rounding down)." onmousedown="event.preventDefault()" data-packed-dice="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dice&quot;,&quot;rollable&quot;:true,&quot;toRoll&quot;:&quot;2d6 + 8&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;damage&quot;}"><a href="talespire://dice/null:2d6+8" class="talespireLink">(2d6+8)</a></span>) bludgeoning damage and be knocked <a href="conditionsdiseases.html#prone_phb" onmouseover="Renderer.hover.pHandleLinkMouseOver(event, this)" onmouseleave="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseLeave(event, this)" onmousemove="Renderer.hover.handleLinkMouseMove(event, this)" data-vet-page="conditionsdiseases.html" data-vet-source="PHB" data-vet-hash="prone_phb" ontouchstart="Renderer.hover.handleTouchStart(event, this)">prone</a>. The dracolich can then fly up to half its flying speed.</p></li></ul></td></tr><tr><td colspan="6"><b>Source:</b> <i title="Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything">TCE</i>, page 137</td></tr><tr><th class="border" colspan="6"></th></tr></table>
```

Comment: please add your HTML structure?

Comment: Please post the html markup as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @collapsar I have no idea how to get the html from the website in a digestible text format.

Comment: @rogerfoster You copy/paste it into your question, using code formatting (three backticks before, three backticks after the code/markup block).

Comment: `for (setText of currentText)` doesn't really make sense. `currentText` is not an array, you're iterating over the characters of a string instead. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has confusing indentation. The way it is written your code is actually executed as:

```
for (const element of elements) {
    const currentText = element.querySelector('.entry-title-inner').innerText;
    for (setText of currentText)
        setText = element.querySelector('.render-roller');

    console.log(currentText);
    setText.setAttribute("data-roll-name",currentText)
}
```

But I highly doubt this is actually what you intended. You need to add braces to get what you want:

```
for (const element of elements) {
    const currentText = element.querySelector('.entry-title-inner').innerText;
    for (setText of currentText) { // <-- this is EXTREMELY important!!
        setText = element.querySelector('.render-roller');
        console.log(currentText);
        setText.setAttribute("data-roll-name",currentText)
    }
}
```